# cannot install openssh-server

Tags: apt, ssh, 22.04, openssh

I'm having trouble installing OpenSSH server on Ubuntu-22.04.2 (not 22.04.1).

ERROR:

```
$ sudo apt install openssh-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libbsd0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.33) but it is not installable
 libcbor0.8:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libcom-err2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libedit2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.33) but it is not installable
 libfido2-1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.33) but it is not installable
 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.33) but it is not installable
 libk5crypto3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.33) but it is not installable
 libkeyutils1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
 libkrb5-3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 libkrb5support0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 libmd0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.33) but it is not installable
 libpcre2-8-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libselinux1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 libssl3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 libtinfo6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.33) but it is not installable
 libudev1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 openssh-client:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
 zlib1g:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: None of the packages in your paste relate to `openssh-server` ... those are packages related to prior package(s) you installed likely from a poor source that was added   (*a prior problem you didn't fix.. that will remain until fixed*)

Comment: Thanks. I solved it using the method on that page.